# Resize image on the fly using ashx

Tags: c#, ashx

i want to resize image while using ashx handler. I am getting the image from Android App, all code are working fine (the image is store in server directory) but the image is huge very very big. is there some idea to resize the image in ashx handler?

```
HttpPostedFile hpf = context.Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFile;
    if (hpf.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        savedFileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i figured it up

```
HttpPostedFile hpf = context.Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFile;
    if (hpf.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var random = new Random();
        var result = new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                      .ToArray());



        savedFileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);


        string File1 = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
        imageNewval = result + "_ReemEyalLia_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyhhmmss");

        Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(hpf.InputStream);
        decimal origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
        decimal origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
        decimal sngRatio = origHeight / origWidth;
        int newHeight = 200;
        decimal newWidth_temp = newHeight / sngRatio;
        int newWidth = Convert.ToInt16(newWidth_temp);
        Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
        Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
        oGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; oGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Default;
        oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        newBMP.Save(context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + imageNewval + Path.GetExtension(File1)));

        originalBMP.Dispose();
        newBMP.Dispose();
        oGraphics.Dispose();

    }
```